# jQuery each menu item but not sub menu items

Tags: jquery

```
<ul class="main-menu">
    <li>
        <a href="domain.com/host">Host</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu nav">
            <li>
                <a href="domain.com/host/party">Party</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>

$('.main-menu li a').each(function(ev){
        var name = $(this).text();
        console.log(name);
    });
```

The above code lists both `Host` and `Party` when all I want is `Host`

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mynameisdonald/2sxeL/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the child selector instead of the descendant selector:

```
$('.main-menu>li>a').each(function(ev){
    var name = $(this).text();
    console.log(name);
});
```

See http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/ for more information about css selectors or http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ for the jQuery selectors page.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `>` is used to select elements with a specific parent , it only looks one level down the markup structure, no deeper.

```
$('.main-menu>li>a').each(function(ev){
        var name = $(this).text();
        console.log(name);
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/2sxeL/1/)

For more information about css selectors visit **[here](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/)**

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.main-menu > li > a').each(function(ev){
        var name = $(this).text();
        console.log(name);
    });
```

The addition of `>` is all you need - which indicates direct descendents only. Its is called the [child selector](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use parent-child instead of ancestor-descendant.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/)**

```
$('.main-menu > li > a').each(function(ev){
    var name = $(this).text();
    console.log(name);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To use the ***child selector***(`>`).

*Documentation (Child Selector):* http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2sxeL/3/)** Demo

```
$('.main-menu > li > a').each(function(ev){
        var name = $(this).text();
        console.log(name);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **[child-selector](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/)**:

```
$('.main-menu>li>a').each(function(ev){
//code here
});
```